How can I send files given by file_input modal to another workspace in slack?
(Sorry for my poor English...)
Using file_input elements, users can send files. I'd like to send these files to another workspace.
I thought that I need to download the files and then upload using files.getUploadURLExternal and https://slack.com/api/files.completeUploadExternal. However, I cannot find how to download the files.
When modal is submitted, we get a response(*) including file objects as shown here.
I made a GET request to url_private and url_private_download with an authentication header (Bearer xoxp-...) to download the sent file. However, I got 404 error.
Also, I called files.completeUploadExternal method in the same workspace where the modal was shown. files argument is id in response(*). In this way, I got 404 error again.
